# How to validate if checkbox is checked in laravel?

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-4

I have a checkbox in my view

```
<input type="checkbox" id="test5">
```

and I want to validate in my controller if the checkbox is checked

```
if (Input::get('test5') === true) {
     //insert 1
} else {
    //insert 0
}
```

Answer (score 6):

First, a checkbox (any kind of input must) must have a name and a value.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="mycheckbox" value="1" id="test6">
```

Then on your controller you do:

```
Request::get('mycheckbox')
```

This will output the value of your checkbox if it's checked, or `null` if not (browser don't send anything)

```
if (Request::get('mycheckbox')) {
    // Do anything here
}
```

**Note** that the input `id` attribute don't care. The important here is the input `name` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

you can validate everything normally and then when you pass the request to an array with `$data = $request->all();` you can check if the checkbox is checked by just checking if the  'mycheckbox' space is empty like:

```
$dataValidate = $request->validate([
    'something' => 'required|numeric|min:3|max:99',
    'something' => 'required|numeric',
    'something' => 'required|numeric',
    'something' => 'required|alpha_dash',
    'something' => 'required|email',
    'something' => ['required', new SomethingRule],
    'something' => 'required|starts_with:0,+',
    'something' => 'nullable|numeric',
]);
$data = $request->all();
if (empty($data['mycheckbox'])) {
    //something if the checkbox is not checked
}else{
    //something if the checkbox is checked
}
```

This is something that I do from time to time I dunno if it is the best practice but it does the job and does not make anything worse